# StackOverflow Error

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, palindrome

I am writing this program to check if the word which is entered by the user, is a Palindrome(the word reads the same when spelled backwards) or not. I am using recursion, as the task i was given stated so. Apparently my recursive call is correct, as the arguments are changing every time. Yet, i am getting the StackOverflow error. I can not identify the reason for the error. What is the problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeChecker {

    static StringBuffer mainString, tempString, chString;
    static int j = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input the String:");
        mainString = new StringBuffer(input.nextLine());
        tempString = mainString;

        for(int n = 0; n < tempString.length(); n++){
            if(tempString.charAt(n) == ' '){
                tempString.deleteCharAt(n);
                n -= 1;
            }
        }
        chString = tempString;
        tempString.reverse();
        checker(j);

    }


    public static void checker(int k){

        if(k < tempString.length()){
            if(tempString.charAt(k) != chString.charAt(k)){
                System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");

            }
            else
                checker(j+1);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Palindrome Confirmed!");

    } 

}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger yet?

Comment: You could dry run your code to check for the problem

Comment: `checker(j+1)` you probably meant `checker(k+1)`, otherwise you're always calling your function with the same value (`1`)

Comment: This line `checker(j+1)` is the problem, I guess it should be `checker(k+1)`. The code as is means that you continually recurse with the call `checker(1)` (i.e. because j = 0 and doesn't change).

Comment: Style is a personal preference, but those `else` statements with no braces terrify me. If you need to add another line and forget to add braces, your code will break in all sorts of interesting and subtle ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see you never change your j. So checker is called every time with j = 1.

Edit : StackOverFlowError reason is often because you are stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your troubles begin at the point where you are declaring all your variables as `static`.  Thus, they are visible from all of your code, and all of your code can accidentally access them and modify them.

Your problem then continues with invoking `checker(j+1);` where instead you probably meant to do `checker(k+1);`,  The static variable `j` is `0` and never changed, so `j+1` will always be `1`.  So, your function will always recurse.

Comment: OP could also just do `checker(j++)` and it would work. But probably the better approach is to drop `j` entirely and just use `k+1` as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

J+1 means: (the value of the variable j) + 1. 
++J or J++ means add one to the variable j.

the difference here is that when you do j+1 you never assign a new value to your variable J.

So if you need to increment j first do: **checker(++j)**
j will be incremented and then passed to the checker method

If you need to pass j and then increment it do: **checker(j++)**.
j will be pass to the checker method and then incremented